# 2 way binding doesn't work

Tags: knockout.js

When I click the save link for a new blog topic, the console output is empty values for the topic object. When I click the save link for a existing blog topic, the output is the old values for the topic object.

Why isn't the values being assigned the property when the save link is clicked?

```
 var viewModel = function(topics){
        var self = this;
        self.topics = ko.observableArray(topics);
        self.editing_topic = ko.observable("");

        self.new_topic = function(){
            self.edit_topic({});
        }

        self.edit_topic = function(topic){
            self.editing_topic(topic);
            form.dialog({width:800, height:600, modal:true});

        };

        self.save_topic = function(){
            console.log(self.topic());
        };
    };
   ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(jsondata));

<fieldset class="blog_topic_form" title="New Blog Entry">
    <div>
        <label for="topic_title">
            Title:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="topic_title" data-bind="value: topic().topic_title"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message_contents">
            Message:
        </label>
        <textarea id="message_contents" class="message_contents" data-bind="value: topic().message_contents"/>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <a class="save_link" data-bind="click: save_topic"></a>
        <a class="cancel_link"></a>
    </footer>
</fieldset>
```

Edit:
Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jLkxG/3/

When you run it, it will assign the default values. However, if you edit the textbox and click savelink, it will output the original (initial) values instead of the values entered in the textbox.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle for this? I can't tell what the topic() in your binding refers to since it isn't a property of your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code to match the code in the jsfiddle.

In the jsfiddle, your editing_topic properties (topic_title and message_contents) should be defined as observable, not the editing_topic property itself.

I've updated your jsfiddle to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/jLkxG/4/

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided doesn't make complete sense.

I'm assuming the fieldset markup you provided is the contents of the dialog? If that is the case then what are your inputs bound to?

At the moment the text boxes are bound to a topic property on the viewModel but no such property exists. You are also expecting this topic object to have properties topic_title & message_contents but these are not in your model. If you are existing the value binding to create the properties, this is not how it works.

I think you either need to show us more code or provide a fiddle. I took the liberty of copying your code in a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/jLkxG/